# how to stop scroll to specific Div but allow image to slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am using #id on 3 buttons to change image on Slides ,  but i dont want to scroll to images slide section when i click on button just want to slide image to next without scrolling to image section
here is drive video link to show how my web is looking right now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dXMCeBNzkn2c5ChNQfOAVthNBHHsePSp/view?usp=drivesdk

```html
    <div className="carousel carousel-center max-w-md   md:max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto  space-x-24 ">
        <div id="item1" className="carousel-item">
          <img src="/BingWallpaper.jpg" width={896} className="rounded-box" alt="image1" />
        </div> 
        <div id="item2"  className="carousel-item " >
          <img src="/BingWallpaper.jpg" width={896} className="rounded-box"  alt="image2" />
        </div> 
        <div id="item3"  className="carousel-item">
          <img src="/BingWallpaper.jpg" width={896} className="rounded-box" alt="image3" />
        </div> 
      </div>
```

Comment: The image shared is restricted, please make it public

Comment: oK, i had made it public Now

Comment: I think it will be hard to make it work with #id. I would try to call a javascript function to slide the image instead.

Comment: i don't know much js , can you help on this

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event listener to your buttons and prevent the default behaviour. Add an id of "link" to the button and then add an event listener like below. If your button element contains an anchor tag, add the "link" id to anchor tag instead of button.

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```